# R ggplot - How to add a 3rd information to points (apart from colour)

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, shapes

I am trying to create a plot with ggplot that contains 3 different kind of information in one single point. My base is this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)

df_test %>%
  mutate(bin = Correlations < 0) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Lag, y = Correlations)) + 
  geom_beeswarm(aes(colour = Gender, fill = Age), shape=22, size = 2, stroke = 2, dodge.width=.6) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(indifferent = "gray30",
                             Female = "deeppink", 
                             Male = "royalblue1")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(Baby = "gold", Child = "orange",
                               Adult = "red", SeniorI = "turquoise1", 
                               SeniorII = "lawngreen", indifferent = "gray30")) +
  facet_grid(bin ~ ., scale = "free_y") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.6),
        strip.text.y = element_blank())
```

With that code I can display the age and gender very clearly, but I am missing the "Loc" data. My question is now if there is a way to somehow make this visible in the plot, too. Loc-Data only has the 3 different entries that are shown in the dataframe, so only "A", "U" and indifferent. Could I maybe use 3 different shapes that also allow to have 2 colours?

```
structure(list(Variables = c("Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", "Variable1", 
"Variable1", "Variable1"), ICD = c("ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", 
"ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", 
"ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", 
"ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", 
"ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", 
"ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", 
"ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", 
"ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1", "ICD1"
), Correlations = c("0.39", "0.46", "0.4", "-0.13", "-0.22", 
"0.34", "0.45", "0.39", "0.46", "0.3", "-0.15", "-0.27", "-0.33", 
"0.33", "0.43", "0.37", "0.41", "0.35", "0.3", "-0.34", "0.28", 
"0.38", "0.31", "0.38", "0.34", "0.25", "0.33", "-0.29", "0.24", 
"0.18", "0.4", "0.32", "0.4", "0.38", "0.25", "0.35", "0.23", 
"0.21", "0.4", "0.31", "0.43", "0.41", "0.31", "0.22", "0.35", 
"0.24", "0.23", "0.26", "0.2", "0.24", "0.4", "0.32", "0.42", 
"0.39", "0.3", "0.2", "0.35", "0.54", "0.24", "0.32"), pvalue = c("0.01", 
"0", "0", "0.02", "0.01", "0.04", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.04", 
"0.05", "0.02", "0.04", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.01", "0.02", "0.01", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0.01", "0.01", "0.04", "0.03", "0.04", "0", 
"0", "0", "0.01", "0.01", "0", "0.01", "0.03", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0.01", "0", "0.02", "0.04", "0", "0.03", "0.04", "0", 
"0", "0", "0.01", "0", "0.01", "0", "0", "0.01", "0.03"), Age = c("indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "SeniorI", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "SeniorI", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"SeniorI", "SeniorI", "indifferent", "SeniorI", "SeniorII", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "SeniorI", "SeniorI", "SeniorII", "indifferent", 
"SeniorI", "SeniorII", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"SeniorI", "SeniorI", "SeniorII", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "SeniorI", "SeniorI", 
"SeniorI", "SeniorII", "indifferent", "SeniorII", "Adult", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "Adult", "indifferent", "indifferent", "SeniorI", 
"SeniorI", "SeniorI", "SeniorII", "indifferent", "Adult", "SeniorII", 
"indifferent"), Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "indifferent", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "indifferent", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "indifferent", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "indifferent", "indifferent", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "indifferent", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "indifferent", 
"indifferent"), Loc = c("indifferent", "indifferent", "A", "indifferent", 
"A", "U", "indifferent", "A", "indifferent", "U", "indifferent", 
"A", "indifferent", "U", "indifferent", "A", "indifferent", "A", 
"U", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "A", "indifferent", 
"A", "indifferent", "U", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "A", "indifferent", "A", "indifferent", "U", "indifferent", 
"A", "indifferent", "A", "indifferent", "A", "U", "indifferent", 
"U", "indifferent", "indifferent", "indifferent", "A", "indifferent", 
"indifferent", "A", "indifferent", "A", "U", "indifferent", "U", 
"U", "indifferent", "U"), Conditions = c("Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", 
"Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", 
"Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", 
"Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", 
"Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", 
"Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", 
"Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", 
"Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", 
"Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", "Cond1", 
"Cond1"), Lag = c("L0", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", 
"L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L3", "L3", "L3", 
"L3", "L3", "L4", "L4", "L4", "L4", "L4", "L4", "L4", "L4", "L5", 
"L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "L5", "L6", "L6", "L6", "L6", "L6", 
"L6", "L6", "L6", "L6", "L6", "L7", "L7", "L7", "L7", "L7", "L7", 
"L7", "L7", "L7", "L7", "L7", "L7", "L7", "L7")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

Comment: You sure can! Shapes 21-25 all allow for two colors. Search "R pch" for a key to the available shapes.

Comment: Thanks, but where in the code do I implement them? Could you please give me an example? 21, 22, 23 would be great to have.

Comment: Oh thanks! I got it now, but my legend is totally messed up now. It doesnt show the correct colors anymore.

Comment: On "age" I only get black dots, not colored dots.

Comment: Consider updating your question based on what you've figured out so far. :) For legend fill colors you may end up needing `override.aes` to change the shape in the legend to a fillable shape. You can see a basic example of this [here](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2020/07/09/ggplot2-override-aes/#controlling-the-appearance-of-multiple-legends).

Comment: Thank you! Override is needed there. Seems like the legend automatically uses not fillable symbols. I got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

For `geom_point` we have the followin aesthetics (required aesthetics are in bold):

- **x**
- **y**
- alpha
- colour
- fill
- group
- shape
- size
- stroke

Here is an example of some of then applied

### Plot code

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(drat,hp, col = as.factor(gear)))+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(
    size = as.factor(am),
    alpha = as.factor(vs),
    shape = as.factor(cyl)
  ))
```

#### Plot output

[image]